# VB Net access to form control by their variable names

Tags: vb.net

From a FormName2, and I need to set a text in a TextboxName1 that is in a FormName1, by their string names.

Then, from FormName2, I should set the text like `FormName1.TextboxName1.text = "test"`.
However, I need to achieve it with string names of the controls.

```
stringFormName.stringTextboxName.text ="test"
```

How to reach it?

Comment: Forms instance can be retrieved from the Application.OpenForms collection, control instance can be retrieved from the form Controls collection

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve all the opened instances of your forms in the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection.
Using that collection you can retrieve the form with the specified name

```
Dim aForm = Application.OpenForms.Item("FormName1")
```

At this point, you can scan the controls of this form with the same pattern for a control with a specific name

```
If aForm IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim aControl = aForm.Controls.Item("TextBoxName1")
   if aControl IsNot Nothing then
      aControl.Text = "test"
   End If
End If
```

The only problem with this search for a control is the possibility of the control to be contained in a control container different from the top level form. For example the control could be inside a GroupBox or a Panel. In this case you need to use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method from the Control collection with the second parameter set to true to search all the control hierarchy

```
  Dim aControl = aForm.Controls.Find("TextBoxName1", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use FindControl:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, MyEventArgs As EventArgs)
    Dim myControl1 As Control = FormName1.FindControl("stringTextboxName")
    If (Not myControl1 Is Nothing)
       ' Get control's parent.
       Dim tb as TextBox= CType(myControl1, TextBox)
       tb.text="test"
    Else
       Console.WriteLine("Control not found.....")
    End If
    End Sub
```

If you have nested elements you may need to call find control recursively.